# How to feed information from off site database

Tags: xml, feed

I need to create a page on a website to allow an estate agents property to automatically upload  from their CRM/ Property Software onto the website.

It will display photos and measurements ect

They have XML and FTP access.  Is this the best way to upload  and if so how is this practically done?

example page :
https://www.foxtons.co.uk/search?submit_type=search&sold=1&location=

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is available in XML export, then agents can be provided a login page to upload this XML file on the website. Once the file is available on the Web Server, a batch job can be written to read these files and insert the data into required tables of the website (that you are creating page for). Prior to writing the data to tables, I believe some sort of data transformation might be required to ensure that source data is transformed into target state so that it can render correctly on the website.

Depending upon the technology stack of the website (assuming it is Microsoft, option could be to write SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) job in the background to do the transformation.

Comment: If data is available in XML export, then agents can be provided a login page to upload this XML file on the website. Once the file is available on the Web Server, a batch job can be written to read these files and insert the data into required tables of the website (that you are creating page for). Prior to writing the data to tables, I believe some sort of data transformation might be required to ensure that source data is transformed into target state so that it can render correctly on the website. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: many thanks  . what would be an example of a 'batch job'  or 'data transformation' method?

Comment: An example would be say, that source provides you length and breadth of the floor and in say inches, however on website you want to show length and breadth in feet along with area, then before insertion into table, you would have to not only convert measurement units for length and breadth, you would also need to calculate area before you insert the data in target table.